# PHP multiple file upload issue

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form to upload files to the server which is given below:

```
<form action="/upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<? foreach($this->devices as $d): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?=$d['id']?>"/> 
    <?=$d['site']?>
<? endforeach ?>

Select Directory:
<select name="optone" size="1" onchange="setOptions(document.myform.optone.options[document.myform.optone.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="0">Select the directory</option>
    <option value="usr">/usr</option>
</select>
Select subdirectory:
<select name="opttwo" size="1">
<option value=""></option>
</select>

Choose files to upload: <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" onchange="filesProcess(this.files);" /><br />
<output id="list"></output>
<input type="submit" value="Update" style="align:center"/>
</form>
```

The upload function is given below:

```
$count=count($_FILES['files']['name']);
    $i=0;
    if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check)
        {
            $dir=$_POST['optone'];
            $subdir=$_POST['opttwo'];
            $dir_folder=$dir."_".$subdir;
            exec(mkdir("firmware_update/".$check."/",0777));
            exec(mkdir("firmware_update/".$check."/".$dir_folder."/",0777));
            while($i<$count)
            {
                $f=$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $name=$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $path="firmware_update/".$check."/".$dir_folder."/".$name;
                move_uploaded_file($f,$path);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

According to the form, I need to select sites from checkbox(eg:56,68 etc), a directory(eg:usr,bin) from drop down menu, a subdirectory(eg:usr,etc) from the second drop down menu and the files to upload. The upload function is working good except a small problem.

All files which we selected should be uploaded to different folders. But the above code is only uploaded the files to the first folder only.
Eg: If we select the check boxes 56 and 68, directory usr and sub directory bin and the file name is test.php. The file test.php should be uploaded to 56/usr_bin/ and 68/usr_bin. But now the code is only working for first (56/usr_bin/). Where did I make mistake?
Any help should be appreciated!

Comment: `exec(mkdir("firmware_update/".$check."/".$dir_folder."/",0777));` why have the `$dir_folder` here? and yet set again at `$path`

Comment: $dir_folder will give the value like usr_bin. I can see 56/usr_bin/ and 68/usr_bin. But test.php only in the first foleder, 56/usr_bin/.

Comment: But I have set $i=0. I have tried 4 check boxes, but the files only uploaded to the first one only!

Comment: i see try to make some error checking it uploading doesnt failed for others..

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are uploading a single file to different folders and `$_POST['check_list']` determines the folders.

If it is the case, Can you move `$i=0` to `foreach` loop? I hope its why the issue happens.

Please try this code.

```
$count=count($_FILES['files']['name']);

    if(!empty($_POST['check_list']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check)
        {
            $i=0;
            $dir=$_POST['optone'];
            $subdir=$_POST['opttwo'];
            $dir_folder=$dir."_".$subdir;
            exec(mkdir("firmware_update/".$check."/",0777));
            exec(mkdir("firmware_update/".$check."/".$dir_folder."/",0777));
            while($i<$count)
            {
                $f=$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $name=$_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $path="firmware_update/".$check."/".$dir_folder."/".$name;
                move_uploaded_file($f,$path);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
```